# Why is everything confused up in thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics

[image]

Is the formula application done properly when calculating work. I think the volume should be final minus the initial. So in first step it should be $V_1-V_i$ and in second step it should be $V_f-V_1$. But totally different things are given and I can't understand. There is also the graph based on this and conclusions too. I wonder whether they are correct. Please help me.why is it so confusing?

Comment: What in your opinion should the work be?

Comment: @ChesterMiller yeah I have written it in the question. My problem is with the volume term in the work

Comment: @ChesterMiller sir please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a two-step process.  In the first step, the mass m1 is removed from atop m2, and the system is allowed to re-equilibrate.  In this step, if I do a Newton's law force balance on the combination of the piston (assumed massless) and m2, I get:  $$F_g-m_2g-P_{atm}A=m_2\frac{dv}{dt}$$where $F_g(t)$ is the force exerted by the gas on the base of the piston during step 1, A is the area of the piston, and v is the velocity of the piston.

If I multiply this equation by the velocity of the piston $\frac{dx}{dt}=v$, I get:$$F_g\frac{dx}{dt}=m_2g\frac{dx}{dt}+P_{atm}A\frac{dx}{dt}+m_2v\frac{dv}{dt}=\left[\frac{m_2g}{A}+P_{atm}\right]\frac{dV}{dt}+\frac{1}{2}m_2\frac{dv^2}{dt}$$where V is the volume of gas at time t.

If I integrate this equation from t = 0 to arbitrary time t during the process, I obtain:
$$W_g(t)=\int{F_gdx}=\left[\frac{m_2g}{A}+P_{atm}\right][V(t)-V_i]+\frac{1}{2}m_2v^2(t)$$where $W_g(t)$ is the work done by the gas on the combination of piston and m2 up to time t, V(t) is the volume of gas at time t, $V_i$ is the initial volume of gas, and v(t) is the velocity of the combination of piston and m2 at time t.  The final term on the right hand side of the equation represents the kinetic energy of the combination of piston and m2 at time t.

What do you think will happen to the velocity of the combination of piston and m2 at very long times?

(a) the velocity will continue increasing forever

(b) the velocity will slow down gradually until the piston and m2 finally stop at the equilibrium position $V_1$

(c) the piston and mass will overshoot the equilibrium position (until their velocity slows to zero), reverse direction and overshoot the equilibrium position going in the other direction (until their velocity slows to zero again), reverse direction again, etc.  They will oscillate about the equilibrium position forever (like a mass/spring system in simple harmonic motion)

(d) same as (c), except that, even if the piston is frictionless, viscous damping stresses in the gas will ultimately damp out the oscillation until the combination of piston and m2 settle at the equilibrium position $V_1$

Actually, the correct answer is (d).  However, I suppose (b) would be possible if the gas were somehow very viscous.  Either way, however, the conclusion is the same.  At final equilibrium of step 1, the piston is no longer moving.  So the amount of work that the gas does on the combination of piston and m2 when final equilibrium is attained in step 1 is just:

$$W_{g1}=\left[\frac{m_2g}{A}+P_{atm}\right][V_1-V_i]$$This is the result they obtained in your reference (aside from the sign (since they are considering work done by the surroundings on the system, and I am considering work done by the system, in this case the gas, on its surroundings).

Comment: If you look closely sir they have written Vi-V1. That's what bothering me(leaving off signs) . Again in second step we must go from V1 to Vf in the integral but they have given Vi to Vf. Am I correct?

Comment: I'm okay with what you have explained me sir

Comment: Yes, you're correct.  That's a typo.

Comment: then what do i do with the graph sir. how is the work done in two step greater than that in one step?

Comment: I don’t understand this question.

Comment: sir I'm just asking how is the work more in two step process of than that in one step

Comment: In the two step process, first the gas does some work, and then in the 2nd step it does some more work.  So the total amount of work is more the if it just did the first step.

Comment: But when I look at the graph the shaded region is less in area than in one single step. In one step ,the integral would give me the whole are under the P-V curve. Am I correct?

Comment: No.  The gas re-equilibrates after removing m1, while doing as much work as it can on m2 and the external atmosphere.  For it to do more work, you remove m2.  It then does more work, but only on the external atmosphere, since m2 has now been removed.  So the total work is what they have shown in the figure.  In step 1, you are doing work on m2 and the external atmosphere, but in step 2 you are doing work only on the external atmosphere.

Comment: You can't do the whole thing in one step because, with m1 removed, the gas can't expand beyond V1, since this is the volume at which it reaches equilibrium.

Comment: yes sir now I understand this.

Comment: Since we are doing work against a pressure higher than the atmospheric pressure the work his higher . Whereas in case of reversible expansion we do work only against the atmosphere in the whole process

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84277/discussion-between-chester-miller-and-vigneshwaran).